# How to load dropdowns and pass values using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

using Python and Flask I have this Flask file which should take a couple of inputs from the user and pass those to a python script to be used. I can get 2 boxes that will accept numbers as inputs and those work just fine using the code below.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os
import csv
import fileinput
import codecs
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import notnull   
from races import calculate_mode
from races import do_calculation
#import races
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["DEBUG"] = True

inputs = []
    @app.route("/testing", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def testing():
        errors = ""        
        number1 = None
        number2 = None
        colours = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Black', 'Orange']
    
        if request.method == "POST":
    
            try:
                number1 = float(request.form["number1"])
            except:
                errors += "<p>{!r} is not a number.</p>\n".format(request.form["number1"])
            try:
                number2 = float(request.form["number2"])
            except:
                errors += "<p>{!r} is not a number.</p>\n".format(request.form["number2"])
    
        if number1 is not None and number2 is not None:
            result = do_calculation(number1, number2)
            
            return '''
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <p>The result is {result}</p>
                        <p><a href="/">Click here to calculate again</a>
                    </body>
                </html>
            '''.format(result=result)
    
        return '''
            <html>
                <body>
                    {errors}
                    <p>Enter your numbers:</p>
                    <form method="post" action=".">
                        <p><input name="number1" /></p>
                        <p><input name="number2" /></p>
                        <p><input type="submit" value="Do calculation" /></p>
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>
        '''.format(errors=errors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But for this application it really needs to be drop down boxes. I have gotten a dropdown box to load using something like this:

```
@app.route("/dropdown", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def select():

    colours = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Black', 'Orange']
    return render_template('select.html', colours=colours)
```

However I don't know how to pass arguments from a newly loaded page and the python file. So instead I'm trying to load the html in the same file by replacing the second 'return' with the code below (which is basically the same as the file that is loaded with select.html) but can't get the dropdown to work (error is KeyError: '% for colour in colours')

```
return '''
    <html>
        <form>
            <select name="colour" method="POST" action="/">
                <option value="{{colours[0]}}" selected>{{colours[0]}}</option>
                {% for colour in colours[1:] %}
                    <option value="{{colour}}">{{colour}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Do calculation" /></p>
        </form>
    </html>
'''.format(errors=errors)
```

Does anyone know why it won't work, or have a better idea of how to do this?

Comment: your new `return` doesn't runs `render_template` so it doesn't get `colours`. You should ratern generate string and later use `return render_template_string(new_string, colours=colours)`. OR even you could send errors directly to template `return render_template_string(new_string, colours=colours, errors=errors)` without usning `.format()`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `.format()` to format HTML and `format` treats all `{ }` as places for variables - even `{%...%}` - and it doesn't know what means this `{% ... %}`.

You should use `render_template_string()` instead of `format()`

```py
if number1 is not None and number2 is not None:
            result = do_calculation(number1, number2)

            html = '''
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <p>The result is {{ result }}</p>
                        <p><a href="/">Click here to calculate again</a>
                    </body>
                </html>
            '''
  
            return render_template_string(html, result=result)

html =  '''
    <html>
        <form>
            {{ errors }}
            <select name="colour" method="POST" action="/">
                <option value="{{ colours[0] }}" selected>{{colours[0]}}</option>
                {% for colour in colours[1:] %}
                    <option value="{{ colour }}">{{ colour }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Do calculation" /></p>
        </form>
    </html>'''


return render_template_string(html, colours=colours, errors=errors)
```

or

```py
if number1 is not None and number2 is not None:
            result = do_calculation(number1, number2)
  
            return render_template_string('''
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <p>The result is {{ result }}</p>
                        <p><a href="/">Click here to calculate again</a>
                    </body>
                </html>
            ''', result=result)


return render_template_string('''
    <html>
        <form>
            {{ errors }}
            <select name="colour" method="POST" action="/">
                <option value="{{ colours[0] }}" selected>{{colours[0]}}</option>
                {% for colour in colours[1:] %}
                    <option value="{{ colour }}">{{ colour }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Do calculation" /></p>
        </form>
    </html>''', colours=colours, errors=errors)
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Do you know how to return the selected value? I've tried adding a name to this line:  <option value="{{ colours[0] }}" selected>{{colours[0]}} name="colorselected"</option> and then trying something like: colorselected = request.form["colorselected"] but I keep getting BadRequestKeyError: 400 KeyError: 'colorselected'

Comment: you have `<select name="colour" >`  and you should use `request.form["colour"]`. Putting name in `option` is useless - browser will use `name` from `<select>` to send selected value. And you don't even put name in `<option>` (`<option name=...>`) but in `HTML` between `<option>` and `</option>`